# How to summ all cv::Mat elements?

Tags: c++, opencv

I trying to make the fast character recognition algorithm.

I have the result of absdiff() and now I want to summ all of this cv::Mat to find out small or big difference it is.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenCV function sum() adds the elements for all dimensions of a matrix:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum

```
Scalar result = sum(A);
```

Comment: int result = sum(A).val[0]/(mat.cols*mat.rows);